# marking columns in sqlalchemy tables

Tags: python, solr, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to add a custom attribute "searchable" to the columns in an sqlalchemy model. The purpose is to extract data for just these columns (using ModelFoo.__ table__.columns) and put the data into solr. Is there a way I can mark certain columns using a custom attribute?

```
class ModelFoo(AppBase):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    os = Column(String, nullable=False, searchable=True)
    platform = Column(String, searchable=True)
```

by default, I get the following error when I try the above:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Unknown arguments passed to Column: ['searchable']
```

I am looking for a generic way to add only "searchable" columns to solr,  something along these lines:

```
for table in Base.metadata.tables.values():
    keys = [str(key) for key in table.columns if key.searchable] 
    solr.add(session.query(*keys).all())
```

in the above code, I am looking for some short solution or alternative to get "key.searchable" to work. Hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Your question is little Uncleared. What data you want and where do you put data?

Comment: I want to put only certain fields data into solr, not the entire object as shown here: http://opensource.timetric.com/sunburnt/addingdocuments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using a separate attribute in model:

```
class ModelFoo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    os = Column(String, nullable=False)
    platform = Column(String)
    search_cols = ["os", "value"]

for k, v in list(Base._decl_class_registry.items()):
    if (hasattr(v, "search_cols")):
        cols = [getattr(v, val) for val in v.search_cols]
        query = sess.query(*cols)
        solr.add(query.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on your question but it looks like your are trying to do something like this from the [link](http://opensource.timetric.com/sunburnt/addingdocuments.html) you provided:

```
si.add(Book.objects.all())
```

Where `Book.objects.all()` is a list of records from an ORM mapped table. Note that the docs say a list of objects is also acceptable. I think to solution here is to use the SQLAlchemy query method to build records with only the fields you want. Using your example with would look like this:

```
si.add(session.query(ModelFoo.os, ModelFoo.platform).all())
```

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I want but I am looking for a generic solution that can be applied to any model. Let me update the original question giving some clarity.

Comment: If you really need to add the attribute you can do this outside the class definition with `ModelFoo.os.searchable = True`. I'm not sure what this gets you though since there is no "generalized" solution. You either have to define what the "searchable" columns are in a query or in the ORM definition.